# $S = \{n: n \text{ is an integer and } n=n^n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S = {n: n \text{is an integer and} n= n^n}$. What elements are in $S$? I thought simply $1$ and $0$ but I'm not sure if $-1$ is since $-1$ only works sometimes.

Comment: But is well know that $0^0=1$

Comment: I think most mathematicians maintain that $0^0$ is of an indeterminate nature.

Comment: @Xoque55 In the context of the Set Theory $0^0=1$ is a theorem

Comment: How can it only work *sometimes*?! The truth value of $(-1)^{-1}=-1$ ought to be the same at all times.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Fair enough. Then I would only consider $-1,1$ to elements of the set.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Why is that a theorem of set theory?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Do you just mean that there's only one function from $\emptyset$ to itself (the empty function)?

Comment: @QuinnCulver Yes is the empty function. See page 4. https://mathsaber.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/002.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've sort of pointed out, $S$ contains $\Bbb Z^* = \{1,-1\}$. Now we prove that any number in $S$ has to be in $\Bbb Z^*$ (is $1$ or $-1$). Let $n\in S$. Then $$n = n^n$$
Now, we go up to $\Bbb Q$ for a bit and multiply by $n^{-1}$, assuming $n$ isn't $0$. Now we have $$1 = n^{n-1} = nn^{n-2}$$

Suppose that $|n| \geq 2$. In this case, if $n^{n-2}$ is an integer, then $n$ has an inverse in $\Bbb Z$ (namely $n^{n-2}$). But this means that $n = \pm 1$, a contradiction. Therefore when $|n|\geq -2$, $n^{n-2}$ is not an integer. Write $n^{n-2} = \frac{a}{b}$, with $a,b$ coprime. However, $n^n= n^{n-2}n^2$ is an integer by hypothesis. This means that $b\mid n^2$: Putting this together: $$n^{n-2} = \frac{n^n}{n^2} = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{qn^2}\Rightarrow a = qn^n$$
By the coprimality assumption, $q = 1$ and $n^n$, $n^2$ are coprime. But then $\mathrm{gcd}(n^n,n^2) = n^2 = 1$, contradiction. Therefore $|n|\leq 1$. Lastly, $0$ is not in $S$ because $0^0 = 1$ (in this context), so $n$ must be either $1$ or $-1$.

**Edit:** I'll leave this up just because it was a nice exercise for me. For a very simple proof see the comments though.

Comment: Your argument that $n$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}$ only works if $n^{n-2}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$ as well, and there's no _a priori_ reason to believe that's so (it's certainly not for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}$!)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think I've fixed it. Is the proof necessarily this convoluted though? This is all I could come up with.

Comment: It's definitely not necessarily that convoluted.  If $n\lt-1$ then $n^n$ isn't an integer; if $n\geq 2$ then $n^n\geq n^2=n\times n\geq 2\times n\gt n$.